# Can an aarakocra grapple using their feet?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple, aarakocra

Can an [aarakocra](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/aarakocra) player character grapple using their feet?

I've gotten into debates on this subject. Some (including myself) say that it should be possible to do. However, most - if not all - of the DMs I play with disagree. They state that a fly speed of 50 feet is game-breaking as it is, and that being able to grapple using their feet is too overpowered, as no other race is able to do such a thing and it's not given as a mechanical option (e.g. in the Talons trait).

The [grappling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) rules also state that you must use a free hand, but creatures such as the [harpy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/harpy) don't have such a restriction.

With aarakocra being part-bird, I feel it's a safe assumption to say it's possible while still having the other restrictions of a normal grapple, except that both hands are left free. To me (and a few others), it seems that with aarakocra being part-bird, it should come as a second nature of sorts, especially compared to earlier editions when their hands and wings took the same space.

I haven't found a ruling stating that they can't, but also none that say they can. A friend of mine has always had a houserule (which I then stole) that a grapple can be done even without a "free hand" if you have a way to restrict the target (like turning into a snake and coiling around them). I know some things can go unexplained and left open to interpretation in the rules, so I wanted to know if this was a special case allowed by the official rules or not.

Comment: This sounds like it's something you _want_ to be true, even though deep down you know it _isn't_, and want people on the internet to justify your houserule to you so you can attempt to convince other DMs. A better question might be asking what the balance implications would be for houseruling what you want, rather than trying to find evidence for something that doesn't exist.

Comment: yes! I had this in mind for the PC race, and I will admit, its some thing I do want to be true, even though in my heart of hearts I know it wont be, though im not to concerned if it isnt, always been a houserule of a friends (which I then stole) that a grapple can be done if you have a way to restrict them (like turning into a snake and pulling a coil type deal) but starting on houserules like that could have spoiled me, and I know some things can go unexplained and left open to interpretation, which is for the most part why I was asking, just to see if it was a special case or not.

Comment: This sounds like what you're really asking is "Can an Aarakocra pick up enemies and fly away, in order to abduct them, drop them, or otherwise mess with them?"

Answer (score 12):

### Feet cannot be used for grappling

You've answered your own question.  The grappling rules state that you must use a free hand (PHB p.195), and the [aarakocra](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/aarakocra) does not have more than the usual two hands.  There is no "ruling" stating explicitly that they can't use their feet, because the default grappling rules already make clear that this isn't an option.  This is a case where any rules support would have to come from a specific exception to the general rule; and at the moment, such an exception does not exist.

### Would a house-ruled exception be balanced?

It's hard to say, but I'd lean towards "no."  The sole fact that you could grapple with your hands full is powerful, but probably not game-breaking.  But aarakocra already have powerful options for grappling that are not available to the average character.

The difficulty comes from the fact that a fly speed opens the opportunity to grapple, fly up (at half speed,) and then drop the target, resulting in 2d6 bludgeoning damage plus the prone condition.  This is a straight improvement over the shove special melee attack, and a particularly strong one, at that.  Being able to do *this* with your hands full is far from negligible.  In other words, even if were balanced to allow (for example) the [kenku](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/kenku) to do this with their bird-like feet, the aarakocra's already enhanced ability to grapple means that anything that makes grappling easier for them is likely to have a greater impact on their strategy and effectiveness.

In short, there is no RAW support for being able to grapple with your feet, and it's powerful enough that giving the ability to do so on a house-rule could lead to problems.  To be clear, the aarakocra can still grapple using its hands, the same as any other player race.  It can even do so while flying, as its arms are separate from its wings.

If you'd like to experiment with this, I'd suggest making it a custom feat, perhaps along the lines of Tavern Brawler (giving this ability along with very minor additional benefits.)

Comment: It may also be worth noting that in 5e, an aarakocra's wings are separate from their arms, as shown in the [EEPC's official art for the race](https://media.dnd.wizards.com/EE-Players-Companion_0_0.pdf#page=4). (The [D&D Beyond page for the race](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/aarakocra) seems to currently use the art from the *Monster Manual* instead; it's apparently intentional (for whatever reason), but in any case, it's a second example of the wings being separate.) As Mark Wells guesses in a comment on the question, OP may not have realized that fact when they asked the question.

Comment: @V2Blast I'm not a *5e* guy, but that's what confused me about this. Illustrations seem to depict the *5e* aarakocra as a creature with 6 limbs and 2 hands, and flying takes 2 limbs and grappling takes a third (one with a hand). So it seems that an aarakocra can *already* do what this answer describes: grab and drop. The reason it would want to grapple with its feet is *either* that it looks cool *or* so that it can continue to carry its own stuff in both its hands *or* to use a greatsword or whatever against the grappled foe. Is the art wrong? Are the rules for this not mentioned in this Q&A?

Comment: The aarakocra *can* already do that.  I was trying to emphasize that doing all that in addition to having both of its hands full is even more powerful than a non-flying race getting to grapple with its hands full.  In other words, even if this is a safe house-rule for, say the kenku (which also are quite bird-like,) it might not be for the aarakocra.  I will try to rephrase to make that more clear.

Comment: @HeyICanChan To be really clear, the aarakocra isn't prevented from grappling while flying _by lack of hands_ (or else it would be prevented from doing lots of things, like holding weapons). It's very likely that a DM will see you grab-and-drop someone once, and then say "That's cute, now let's talk about encumbrance in flight."

Comment: @MarkWells Cool. Thank you. So this answer's saying that while the game supports the useful and powerful combat tactic of grappling, flying up, and dropping the grappled foe, this answer would have the DM say *no* for game balance? I get that, I guess, but I'd like to think *some* attempt was made to *design* these game elements with this in mind. (It's not like it's far-fetched or anything!) Is airborne encumbrance different from normal? (In *3e* it is—natural flight's limited to light or less encumbrance.) If it is, should that encumbrance factor be it's own rules-based answer?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I am not trying to comment in this answer on whether the RAW grappling options available to the aarakocra are balanced.  Mark's assertion that they shouldn't be allowed by the DM is reasonable, but as far as I know not supported in the 5e rules.  The only assertion I'm making regarding power level is that the aarakocra's already powerful RAW grapple options make any additional buffs to its grappling ability highly suspect.